# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, twitter, typeerror

I took a udemy course where instructor teach about how to get user tweet.

when i run code it gives me

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

not getting good support on udemy so how to make this code work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soupy

import urllib.request
import re

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://twitter.com/samad_bloch0x1').read()

soup = soupy(html, features="html.parser",)

x = soup.find('p', {'class':'js-tweet-text'}).getText()

filter = re.findall(r'"(.*)"', x)ut
tweet = filter[0]  

print(tweet)
```

This is my whole code

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

*First at all, take a closer look into your soup - There is the truth.*

**`None`** is returned, cause `beautifulsoup` could not find the element you try to select - So are you sure there is an element with such this class `js-tweet-text` in the source and the soup?

Follwowing could also be a reason:

> ## JavaScript is not available.
>
> We’ve detected that
> JavaScript is disabled in this browser. Please enable JavaScript or
> switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com. You can
> see a list of supported browsers in our Help Center.

#### What can you do?

- use offical [api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs)
- use proxies
- try to use selenium

##### Example Selenium 4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path='YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://twitter.com/samad_bloch0x1')

# if selenium is to slow you may have to wait -> https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

print(soup.select('[data-testid="tweet"]'))

driver.close()
```

Comment: I don't see js-tweet in a tweet source, im noob in a coding could you please try the code and fix it to get a tweet from the url provided ?

Comment: This is exactly why you are getting the error message and why I asked if you are really sure that the class `js-tweet-text` exists in your `soup` or source - Do not waste your time and start interacting wit the offical [twitter api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs) if you do not like starting from scratch take a look at [tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#introduction) Happy coding